# UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem allows to press navigation button twice

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I am using this code below for presenting UIPopoverController view:

```
[popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

So everything works good, but I am still able to press UIBarButtonItem which a sender in the code above.

So do I need to disable this button when the popover is shown by my self or there is some another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method instead, where `toolbar` is the view containing the sender:

```
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:toolbar permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: The sender in this case is a `UIBarButtonItem`, so there is no superview.